# Documentar software

Tags: administración-de-software

Debo realizar la documentación de una aplicación y me han dado una plantilla con dos apartados a rellenar pero no se muy bien la diferencia:

**2. PROCESO DE NEGOCIO**

**2.1. DESCRIPCIÓN FUNCIONAL**

Entiendo que la descripción funcional sería describir cada operativa o función de la aplicación, pero ¿qué significa el **proceso de negocio**?

Comment: [Esta no es la página que estás buscando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Esto si entra en la tematica del sitio ver https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/163/2027

Comment: No tengo muy claro que entre dentro de la temática del sitio (al menos no definida en la respuesta enlazada). Esto no parece una pregunta conceptual de desarrollo (que sería un problema específico de desarrollo), sino una pregunta sobre documentación/conceptos que realmente no está asociados al desarrollo de software.

Comment: Es peor, porque en realidad no sabemos que se definio para cada apartado de la documentacion. La pregunta no tiene respuesta salvo dentro del lugar de trabajo de OP.

Answer (score 2):

**PROCESO DE NEGOCIO**

Dentro de tu aplicación, los procesos de negocio son la lógica de la misma. Es decir, cómo funciona el flujo dentro de tu aplicación, aquí definiría la estructura de tu aplicación. ¿Cómo interactúan los distintos componentes de tu aplicación hasta llegar a completar el flujo?

**DESCRIPCIÓN FUNCIONAL**

Funcionamiento de la aplicación a nivel funcional, es decir, nos abstraemos de la lógica interna de la aplicación y la explicamos a nivel de funcionamiento. Esta parte no debería ser técnica puesto que el cliente debería poder entenderla perfectamente. Aquí metería los documentos de casos de uso, diagramas uml si procede...

Como consejo para la descripción funcional intentaría seguir el patrón de casos de uso, como usuario tengo que ser capaz de hacer... (sustituye usuario por el actor de tu caso de uso y los puntos suspensivos por la lógica que realice la aplicación).

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Te sugiero revises [answer] para que sepas como responder. Este tipo de pregunta basadas en opiniones no cumplen las reglas del [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)